# How to bind DataTable to Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a problem binding a `DataTable` to a `DataGrid`. I have already searched for solutions but just can't get rid of the error. *The binding works fine when using WindowsForms, so the `DataTable` is correct.* I just can't bind it to a WPF-DataGrid.

> **Error message:** AmbiguousMatchException was unhandled
>   Source: mscorlib

I have already set up new project to get rid of any bad links, etc.

**XAML-Code:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>
```

**I have already tried following C#-Code behind:**

```
grid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

or

```
grid1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
```

or

```
grid1.DataContext = dtex;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show your `DataTable` structure. Also, you don't need to set `ItemsSource` in xaml if you are doing that from code behind.

Comment: The DataTable is filled via SQLDataAdapter. Table is filled with since I calculate with values of the table. The export method also works fine. It is just the binding to the WPFDataGrid.

Answer (score 67):

In cs file

```
DataTable employeeData = CreateDataTable();
gridEmployees.DataContext = employeeData.DefaultView;
```

In xaml file

```
<DataGrid Name="gridEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me in WPF - the thing is, why doesnt Visual studio automatically adjust the XAML for me when doing this?

Answer (score 12):

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection())
   {
   con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
   con.Open();
   SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT S_no,Name,Father_Name")
   SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter(com);
   System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
   sda.Fill(dt);
   dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
   dataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
   dataGrid1.CanUserAddRows = false;
   }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: By add dataGrid1.AutoGeberateColumns=true; we will get the o/p on the datagrid otherwise it will not show the o/p

Comment: The default value for AutoGenerateColumns is true. So that line isn't really needed.

Answer (score 11):

**In .cs file**

```
grid.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
```

**In xaml file**

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use **DataGrid** in WPF

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table",con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Call Reciept");
da.Fill(dt);
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: The first sentence says: *"I have a problem binding a `DataTable` to a `DataGrid`."* He does indeed use a **DataGrid** as you can tell from the OPs question, so what's the point of this sentence?

Comment: my DataGrid has no ItemsSource but DataContext. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm expecting, as [Rohit Vats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632337/rohit-vats) mentioned in his [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/c-sharp-wpf-bind-datatable-to-datagrid#comment31131137_20770438) too, that you have a wrong structure in your `DataTable`.

#### Try something like this:

```
  var t = new DataTable();

  // create column header
  foreach ( string s in identifiders ) {
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(s)); // <<=== i'm expecting you don't have defined any DataColumns, haven't you?
  }

  // Add data to DataTable
  for ( int lineNumber = identifierLineNumber; lineNumber < lineCount; lineNumber++ ) {
    DataRow newRow = t.NewRow();
    for ( int column = 0; column < identifierCount; column++ ) {
      newRow[column] = fileContent.ElementAt(lineNumber)[column];
    }
    t.Rows.Add(newRow);
  }

  return t.DefaultView;
```

I have used this DataTable in a `ValueConverter` and it works like a charm with the following binding.

#### xaml:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileContent, Converter={StaticResource dataGridConverter}}" />
```

So what it does, the `ValueConverter` transforms my bounded data (what ever it is, in my case it's a `List<string[]>`) into a `DataTable`, as the code above shows, and passes this `DataTable` to the `DataGrid`. With specified data columns the data grid can generate the needed columns and visualize them.

To say it in a nutshell, in my case the binding to a `DataTable` works like a charm.

Comment: Until someone comes up with a more elegant (syntactic sugar, anyone?) way to bind expando objects to PODG (plain ol' data grids), I'm going to use the data table approach. Easy to set up, easy to data-bind.

Comment: As far as I could research there is no more elegant solution in .NET 4.0 to bind a _scaleable_-column DataTable to a DataGrid. There are enough examples around the web to bind _fixed_-column tables. Maybe Microsoft will provide a way in an later release.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
grid1.DataContext = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x < 10).AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable().AsDataView();
```

and do whatever query i want between the two AsEnumerable().
If you don't need space for query, you can just do directly this:

```
grid1.DataContext = dt.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score -2):

In cs file:

```
    private DataTable _dataTable;

    public DataTable DataTable
    {
        get { return _dataTable; }
        set { _dataTable = value; }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._dataTable = new DataTable("table");

        this._dataTable.Columns.Add("col0");
        this._dataTable.Columns.Add("col1");
        this._dataTable.Columns.Add("col2");

        this._dataTable.Rows.Add("data00", "data01", "data02");
        this._dataTable.Rows.Add("data10", "data11", "data22");
        this._dataTable.Rows.Add("data20", "data21", "data22");

        this.grid1.DataContext = this;

    }
```

In Xaml file:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid1"
          Margin="10"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataTable, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: This is equivalent to what OP posted in question. Issue is somewhere in DataTable he's binding to.

Comment: I have method in a separate class which returns a datatable. `table1 = myClassInstance.myMethod();` MessageBox shows that table1 has 4 columns and a couple of rows. I then want to bind table1 to the DataGrid in the WPF.