# how can display data in grid-view or listview from multi XML files in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, asp-classic, report

i need to display data in grid-view or list-view form more than one XML files 
this XML files have the same schema

the second issue this xml files generated Automatically by user 
i mean if the user open any request on the system the xml file created on specific folder so i need to refer to this path no for specific XML file because every time xml file created

thanks for help

Comment: I would read XML into DataSet using the DataSet.ReadXML() method.  Then combine DataTables using linq.  You can then use datagridview.DataSource = dt, where dt is a datatable.

Comment: can more clarification please

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
       DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ds1.ReadXml(@"c:\temp\test.xml");

        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        ds2.ReadXml(@"c:\temp\test.xml");

        ds2.Tables["Product"].Merge(ds1.Tables["Product"]);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds2.Tables["Product"];
```

Comment: i havent any table what did you mean with this step  ds1.Tables["t_Name"]

Comment: A dataset contains datatables which can be indexed by a number or name of the table.  The names of the tables when reading XML is the tag name.  the root tag is the the dataset name and the next tag is usally the datatable name.  The next level of tags are the column names in the datatable.  Depending on complexity of XML you may have multiple datatables.

Comment: i have this XML files (product1.xml - product2.xml) with the same structure                              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: <Table>
 
  <Product>                    
    <Product_id>4</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 4</Product_name>
    <Product_price>4000</Product_price>
  </Product>

 </Table>

Comment: so i put in my c# code datatable name as you said
              DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
              ds1.ReadXml(@"c:\XmlFiles\product.xml");

            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            ds2.ReadXml(@"c:\XmlFiles\productTable.xml");

            ds2.Tables["Product"].Merge(ds1.Tables["Product"]);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables["Product"];                                      but i had error and thanks for your kindly support

Comment: Which line gave the error?  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: you told me that i should write the tag name in the ["t_Name"] which tag i should write and how with tag or as string

Comment: Updated code and fully tested.  New code gives merged results.

Comment: what i should put in this tags  ["t_Name"] and How please ?

Comment: Already corrected in the new code posted.  I read from same file twice.  You should be reading from different files.

Comment: this is all my code and when click my button nothing happened   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
              ds1.ReadXml(@"c:\XmlFiles\product.xml");

            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            ds2.ReadXml(@"c:\XmlFiles\productTable.xml");

            ds2.Tables["Product"].Merge(ds1.Tables["Product"]);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables["Product"];
        }

Comment: Nothing happening is sometimes good because it means up aren't getting an exception.   Try using a DataGridView (not gridview).  Make sure it is large enough to display the data.  Aslo make sure you are getting into the button click code.

Comment: thanks for help , i used datagridview but in Windows Application but i cant use this control in web however iam using web application not Windows so please can you tell me what i can use instead of datagridview and gridview please

Comment: See following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid

Comment: did you mean that i should bind the data with datatable no dataset then put this datatable in gridview ?

Comment: A dataset has datatable(s).  The gridview needs to bind to a table.  Doesn't matter if the datatable is a stand-alone or inside a dataset.