# Reading Data from CSV to Screen output

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, csv

This may not be allowed but I'll ask anyway.

I'm trying to develop a product similar to YALV but for a custom logs.

I have a CSV file that I want to read in and display on screen in a table that can be scrolled, filtered, coloured, etc similarly to YALV.

I have code for reading and deciphering the CSV and outputting in a neat format to another file.  I want to adapt this to get it to screen.

I have experience in C# and C but only console related.  Could someone guide me int he right direction to at least get the file being read in a Window in a similar format to YALV?  What would be my possible steps? I'm unsure where to start....

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for a GUI and you want to code it in C++ I would look at using [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/)

Comment: _@Gavzooka_ It's completely unclear what you're asking about. Would you mind to give some concise examples, of what you want to achieve and what you already tried in your question please.

Comment: At the moment, I've not developed anything.  I want to achieve a product similar to YALV for a custom log that I will read in.  I wish to display it in table format within a dialogue/window.  I just need starting points in regards to what I need to use to do this in terms of objects.

Comment: @Gavzooka What is `YALV `?,Do you expect me to google this myself? Give a screenshot, example of the `.csv` format, etc.

Comment: YALV is for reading logs produced by Log4Net.  Can be found here:  https://yalv.codeplex.com/.  I would add a screenshot but unsure how to, but that link shows the view on the first page.   CSV format for the sakes of simplicity could be an 4 values of varying types separated by a comma between each with a line for each row of data....e.g. 1234,a value, a value, date followed by carriage return and then repeat

Comment: @Gavzooka You may have noticed that there's a [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30129406/edit) button below your question, that's meant for improvement and adding additional information.  Comments isn't the right place to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below displays results in a DataGridView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader();
            DataSet ds = csvReader.ReadCSVFile(FILENAME, true);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];
        }
    }
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}

​
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I am looking for but can't seem to get it working with WPF.  The dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"]; doesn't work.  How can I make this work with WPF and a DataGrid?

Comment: See following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid