# C# FTP File Manipulation & API

Tags: c#, file, ftp

This is more of an optimization than coding problem.

**CASE:**

I have a CSV file on the FTP server, that is updated every 30 minutes and contains product data. To dumb things down, let's assume only ID and quantity.
On the other end, there is API that manages the warehouse. 
It's worth noting that the CSV file contains ~7,000 products, while the warehouse will take only select number of them (max. 800-900, mostly the same ones, some may be included and some discarded in the future).

**GOAL:**

I would like to efficently parse the data from CSV to the API (basically update warehouse stocks).

**IDEAS I CAME UP WITH TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:**

1. Most basic

   - Download the CSV file from FTP server (using FileStream and FTPWebRequest)
   - Copy file content to lists / array
   - request API for product ID's in the warehouse
   - find those ID's among others in list / array and update their quantities accordingly through API again.
2. Everything on the fly

   - Read CSV File line by line
   - in the same loop instance, do all the quantity updating (idea above)
3. Anything else?

**WHAT I'M WORRIED ABOUT:**

1. File being modified during reading. Even though i could easily fit in between those 30 minute gaps, is there a way to proof the solution "in case"?

Comment: That is why we have databases the are designed to work in a multi-user environment and lock object to prevent conflicts.  Why convert to CSV when you have a database the contains the data?

Comment: I'm not converting to CSV. This is a file on FTP server of my products provider. I wish they had been using databases as well.

Comment: It must be coming from a database on the server.  How else is it being generated?  You can read the entire csv using oledb.  See my CSV reader code at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output

Comment: You are right, but them sharing only the CSV file that they made especially for their clients means that they do not want to give access to their database, thus i will have to stick with the CSV file.