# Import space delimited text file without header to datagridview - c#

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyRRI.png)

I want to import some space delimited text files to datagrigview in c#. The sample text file in the image has no headers but the column names should be there in datagridview.

Comment: See my code posted at following webpage.  Set headers to false. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output

Comment: The text files has no headers but the headers should appear as column names in datagridview.

Comment: Where do you get the headers from?  You can change column names in table with following : dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "abc";

Comment: the output of your code shows a blank datagrid.

Comment: The code has worked as posted for a lot of people. Not sure why it failed.