# Reading different CSV with CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Basically what I'm trying to do is to read CSV file using CSVHelper. The trick is that there is more than one file(each time user picks different one) and **each of them has different structure**.

Only thing they share is first col named  "Id", then every of them has different number of cols(from 2 additional up to 5) with different data types.

I tried to do this like  that:

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CountryMap : CsvClassMap<Country>
{
    private List<string> attributeColumns = 
        new List<string> { "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3", "Attribute4", "Attribute5" };

    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id").Index(0);
        Map(m => m.Attributes).ConvertUsing(row =>
            attributeColumns
                .Select(column => row.GetField<string>(column))
                .Where(value => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) == false)
            );
    }
}
```

And then with:

```
using (var reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(FilePath,encoding.UTF8)))
{
    reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CountryMap>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var card = reader.GetRecord<Country>();
    }
}
```

But only what I get is car = null.

I would be really thankful for any tips and answers.

Comment: Use my CSVReader class on following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output.  Results are put into a DataTable.  You can call the class more than once and put 2nd results in a different DataTable.  The use a join to merge two datatables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach would be to simply use the .Net OleDB provide to create a DataTable form the CSV file for you. Since the DataTable will already contain the necessary schema data it should simplify the mapping of the file columns to your internal classes.

```
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.IO;

    namespace App.Data
    {
        public class CsvFileHelper
        {
            public static DataTable ReadAsDataTable(string fileFullName)
            {
                DataTable tableCSV;

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\""))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(fileFullName), connection))
                    {
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet("CSVDataSet");
                        adapter.Fill(ds);

                        tableCSV = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                }

                return tableCSV;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was literally what I was looking for. I didn't know about this because I just started working in C#.