# CsvClassMap inside a custom CsvClassMap

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). To perform mapping between my object and a CSV file I'm using `CsvClassMap`. The class I map to itself contains other classes. Currently, to perform the mapping to the inner classes I use `ConvertUsing` on a `CsvPropertyMap`. An example below. `Car` is my main object and it contains `Engine` and the engine is parsed in a separate method:

```
public sealed class CarMapping : CsvClassMap<Car>
{
    CarMapping()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("CarId");
        Map(m => m.Color).Name("CarColor");
        Map(m => m.YearOfProduction).Name("YearOfProduction");
        Map(m => m.Engine).ConvertUsing(ParseEngine);
    }

    private Engine ParseEngine(ICsvReaderRow row)
    {
        var year = row.GetField<int>("EngineYear");
        var cc = row.GetField<int>("EngineCC");

        return new Engine() 
        {
            Year = year,
            CC = cc,
        };
    }
}
```

This works. But what I would like to achieve is to use a mapping inside another mapping. Something like (hypothetical solution) below:

```
public sealed class EngineMapping : CsvClassMap<Engine>
{
    EngineMapping()
    {
        Map(m => m.Year).Name("EngineYear");
        Map(m => m.Cc).Name("EngineCC");
    }
}
```

And then use `EngineMapping` inside `CarMapping`:

```
public sealed class CarMapping : CsvClassMap<Car>
{
    CarMapping()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("CarId");
        Map(m => m.Color).Name("CarColor");
        Map(m => m.YearOfProduction).Name("YearOfProduction");

        // Not real code. Something I would like to be able to use.
        // Use a mapping inside the current mapping
        Map(m => m.Engine).ConsumeClassMap<EngineMapping>();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use an oledb to read your csv into a datatable then write your own parser.  See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output

Comment: I don't have problem reading the csv and creating objects from the file. That works fine (the first code sample). I get correct object's structure with my current solution. What I want to know is if it's possible to extract part of the mapping into another mapping class and reuse it inside the original mapping.

Comment: The answer is yes provided your input data is layered so you know when the child data starts and ends.  With a CSV file you can have two columns parent name and child name (or multiple child columns for grand-parent, parent, child) to create the layers.  With text files (not csv), you will see headers rows to separate layers/section of the text.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise. What I meant by mapping is `CsvClassMap<T>` class. I use this particular class in some other methods. If I could get one per each class instead of one huge for the main class that would simplify my solution greatly.

Comment: The CsvClassMap is a third party library.  From what I can see there is no way of layering the class based on the CSV inputs to create a child class.  My recommendation is to use my CSVRead to put data into a DataTable.  it is very easy to take the datatable and parse it into parent/child objects.  You can use a Linq GroupBy method to do the partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is referred to as a `Reference` map in `CSVHelper`.

```
...
CarMap()
{
    Map(m => m.Id).Name("CarId");
    Map(m => m.Color).Name("CarColor");
    Map(m => m.YearOfProduction).Name("YearOfProduction");
    References<EngineMap>(m => m.Engine);

    // or if you tuck it away in the Engine class:
    //References<Engine.EngineMap>(m => m.Engine);
}
```

Then you have the rest in a new map in the `Engine` class just like you have it in your post:

```
EngineMap()
{
    Map(m => m.Year).Name("EngineYear");
    Map(m => m.Cc).Name("EngineCC");
}
```

If the CSV doesnt have a header so you are using the index, the indices used might be `2` and `8` since you are still referring to the order in the same CSV.

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a way to do the same but on a list of object. So for instance if the engine from the example were a list of engines how would it be possible to apply the same approach?

Comment: I'd have to check, but I think you could do that with `ConvertUsing` and some linq

Answer (score 0):

this kind of mapping is more natural on json format, with [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com) you can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object)` to convert your objects in json format and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(String);` to back from Json to your object.

here one example:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

i know this is not the answera that you want, but is too long to put it as a comment (and i have no enough reputation to comment).