# Comparing two csv files by column and value and displaying line numbers of differing values

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I'm doing a comparer for two csv files that has columns and corresponding values
for each column on every new line. Columns are specified on the first line of the file. Each line after that contains data for each column.

I'm trying to create a program that can handle files with differing line numbers and number of columns and one that could also display the line number of values that differed and then create a new text file that displays the line number, column name and value of File 1 and File 2.

The comparison should be done based on some identifier instead of line by line.
If some column data was missing specified in the column row, then it could display the number of columns which data was missing.

So for example:
   worker1.csv:

> Name;Age;Height;Gender;
>     Bob;21;190;Male
>     John;35;182;Male
>     Rose;
>     Mary;20;175;Female

worker2.csv

> Name;Age;Height;Gender
>     Bob;21;185;Male
>     John;30;186;Male
>     Mary;

output.csv

> Differences found in Mary:
>     File 2, Line number 3, Missing three values
>     Differences found in Bob:
>     File 1, Line number 1, Height: 190
>     File 2, Line number 1, Height: 185
>     Differences found in John:
>     File 1, Line number 2, Age: 35, Height: 182
>     File 2, Line number 3, Age: 30, Height: 186

How should I do this? I did look into LINQ's Except on both files lines but how can I get the line numbers?

Comment: I would read csv data into DataTables.  There are plenty of info on web to compare two datatables.  See my import code on following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) what did you try so far? Show us your code, please. Please look at [ask]

Comment: Thanks :) This turned out to be more complicated than I though initially. I already tried a messy solution that converted every line to a dict with corresponding keys and values. So 1 file basically formed an list of dictionaries which I then compared with dicts of the other line. While I got it to work somehow, its quite complicated and it breaks very easily if comparable files have a differing number of lines or if the other file has a line with differing amount of values. I have been mostly scrapping my solutions thus far :D

Comment: The last line of output.csv should be File 2, Line number 2, Age: 30, Height: 186

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little more complicated that it first appears. But if you approach it step-by-step, it's doable.

I'm going to assume that you have enough memory to load one of the file's records into a dictionary. If your files are very large, things get a lot more complicated.

The first thing you want to do is load one of the files into a dictionary, indexed by the ID. In my example, I'll assume that the ID is the name. Each record will be recorded in a `FileLine` instance:

```
class FileLine
{
    public int LineNumber;
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public int Height;
    public string Gender;
}
```

And your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, FileLine> File1Lines = new Dictionary<string, FileLine>();
```

Now, read the file into that dictionary:

```
int lineNumber = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("worker1.csv")
{
    // split the line and assign the fields.
    // End up with name, age, height, and gender variables.
    ++lineNumber;
    var theLine = new FileLine(
        LineNumber = lineNumber,
        Name = name,
        Age = age,
        Height = height,
        Gender = gender);
    File1Lines.Add(theLine.Name, theLine);
}
```

Now, you can read the second file, look up the item in the dictionary, and report any differences:

```
lineNumber = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("worker2.csv"))
{
    // split the line and create a FileLine instance.
    // we'll call it line2
    // Then, look to see if that line is in the File1Lines dictionary.
    FileLine line1;
    if (!File1Lines.TryGetValue(line2.Name, out line1))
    {
        // the line didn't exist in the first file
    }
    else
    {
        // Now compare individual fields
        if (line2.Age != line1.Age)
        {
            // report that fields are different
        }
        // Do the same with other fields
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to keep track of lines that were in the first file but not in the second file, then create a `HashSet<string>`, and whenever you find a record in the second file, add the name to the hash set. When you're done with the second file, you can compare your hash set with the keys in the dictionary. So if your hash set is called `FoundRecords`, then you'd have:

```
var recordsNotFound = File1Lines.Keys.Except(FoundRecords);
foreach (var name in recordsNotFound)
{
    // look up item in the dictionary to report not found
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I must say I forgot to mention the real amount of columns in my data: there are actually over 50 possible columns, allthough the amount of lines should not be that huge. Could this solution still be possible with that many columns? Or should I just forget reporting differences column-wise alltogether?

Comment: @Makezu: It's still possible with that many columns. You can elect to create a class like I did, with one property per column, or you can put a dictionary in the class to hold the names and values. It's up to you. But the number of columns shouldn't affect the validity of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

From both foreach-loop, you can find the difference, or using for-loop is also ok:

```
string[] content1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"worker1.csv");
string[] content2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"worker2.csv");
for(int i = 0; i < content1.Length; i++)
{
  // check here every line, i is your line number
}
for(int i = 0; i < content2.Length; i++)
{
  // check here every line, i is your line number
}
```