# how to retrieve lines from csv to sub list

Tags: c#, csv

I have a huge csv file contains lines like below:

```
CityName    CityCode    DistrictName    ZipCode
Adana       1           Çukurova        1780
Adana       1           Feke            1660
Adana       1           İmamoğlu        1700
```

As you think only districtname and zipcode column values change first two rows same for most lines so my model defination for this data:

```
public class City
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int cityCode { get; set; }

        public List<District> districts { get; set; }
    }

    public class District
    {
        public string district { get; set; }
        public string zipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I wonder how I can read and load this data to list:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fullName);
            IQueryable<City> cities = lines.Skip(1).Select(l => new City
            {
                name = l.Split(',')[0],
                cityCode = Convert.ToInt32(l.Split(',')[1]),
                ..
            }).AsQueryable();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use my CSV Reader which reads into a DataTable using oledb. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output

Comment: Thank you but this only reads column names,, how can I fill lines to my list ?

Comment: It read everything into a data table using oledb.  Do you have any blank rows in  csv file?

Comment: No I dont, only 4 iteration occurs in foreach loop.. how can I see the content?

Comment: The foreach is just to to add underscore to column name.  The rows of table are a query into the csv database.  Yes csv is a database technically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csv file has been changed to "|" separated

Complete code using Linq

```
public class City
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cityCode { get; set; }
    public District distict { get; set; }
    public List<District> districts { get; set; }
    public static City Convert(string strCity)
    {
        var strArr = strCity.Split('|');
        var cityObj = new City();
        cityObj.name = strArr[0];
        cityObj.cityCode =int.Parse(strArr[1]);
        cityObj.distict = new District() {district= strArr[2], zipCode = strArr[3] };

        return cityObj;
    }
}

public class District
{
    public string district { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return this.district + ":" + this.zipCode;
    }
}

public class LinqTest
{

    public void ReadCsv()
    {
        var data = File.ReadLines(".\\test.csv").Skip(1)
            .Select(x => City.Convert(x)).GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.name, Code = x.cityCode })
            .Select(x => new City() { name = x.Key.Name, cityCode = x.Key.Code, districts = x.Select(item => item.distict).ToList() });

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Name:{item.name} Code: {item.cityCode} Districts: {string.Join(",", item.districts)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: csv File has been changed to "|" separated

Comment: Amazing.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with doing it like that? You can simply read line by line, include the needed checks for your data on the line and then insert all the structures in a simple list of cities. Like that, I've left he needed comments:

```
List<City> listWithCities = new List<City>(); //create a list of cities
using(StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fullName))//open a reader
{
    string line = String.Empty;
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) //loop lines
    {
        if(!line.Contains(',') || line == String.Empty || line.IndexOf("//") == 0)  //to avoid comments, or empty lines, or lines without separator
            continue;

        if(line.Contains("//"))
            line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - line.Substring(line.IndexOf("//")).Length); //skipping comments of type '//' if you need

        string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if(parts.Length < 4) //there are less than 4 parts, so it's not a valid data line? You may skip that if you want
            continue;

        int indexOfPossiblyExistingItem = Array.FindIndex(listWithCities.ToArray(), cit => cit.name == parts[0]);
        if(indexOfPossiblyExistingItem != -1) //the city exists
        {
            listWithCities[indexOfPossiblyExistingItem].districts.Add(new District {district = parts[2], zipCode = parts[3]}); //adding a new destrict ot the list
        }
        else //city does not exist
        {
            listWithCities.Add(new City{name = parts[0], cityCode = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), disricts = new List<District>(new District[] {new District{district = parts[2], zipCode = parts[3]})}}) //adding new city + 1 disctrict in the list
        }
    }
    file.Close();
}
```