# Insert bulk CSV data into SQLite in less time using c# code

Tags: c#, csv, sqlite

I have 3 million data in my CSV file. I would like to insert these bulk data into SQLite database within 10 -15 minutes. Normally it takes 20 minutes using below code.

My Sample:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="D:\\SQLiteData.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
        if (!File.Exists("D:\\SQLiteData.db"))
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("D:\\SQLiteData.db");
        }
        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
        com.Transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
        com.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Sample([ELEMENT_ID] real,[DATE] datetime,[COMMENT] real);"
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sample] VALUES(@C0,@C1,@C2)";
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("E:\\comma.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(streamReader))
            {
                reader.ValueSeparator =’,’;
                reader.ReadHeaderRecord();
                while (reader.HasMoreRecords)
                {
                    DataRecord record = reader.ReadDataRecord();
                    com.Parameters.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.HeaderRecord.Count; i++)
                    {
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c" + i, string.Empty);
                    }
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone suggest me an alternate way to move bulk CSV data into SQLite in less time?

Comment: "I have a car, I would like you to make it fly please"

Comment: You can check out if SQLite has something like this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql

Comment: Once you have data into data table you can use bulkcopy.  You can read the csv file faster by using oledb.  See my response at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output

Comment: I would try to use a stored procedure and pass a Table to that proc that is filled with a bunch of data at once (not all, which might be too much to hold in a table?). If you make it async, maybe it speeds up the process a little if you prepare the next bunch while the previous is being uploaded.

Comment: Profile it. I seem to recall having to compile a custom version of the managed SQLite wrapper because it was parsing an XML configuration file on every query execution... Also, this will help you determine if it's really the database that's the bottleneck or the CSV reader.

Comment: There are lots of things you could try (except a Bulk Import - it does not exist for SQLite). The main thing is to do as little in code as possible.  There is no need to clear the parm collection each time,  just reset the value; and dont use AddWithValue and make it guess what the datatype is.  *That code* seems to be inserting empty strings for everything and `real` for a comment and Id field seem wrong.  A quick test inserted 1.5 million rows in 33 secs or 45k inserts per second which close to the max you can expect from it.  It can be slower on slower drives.

Comment: Test one: 1.5 Million rows in ~33 secs.  Test two: 5 million rows in about 2 mins.  Streamline your code and DB structure

Comment: @Plutonix: Thanks for your information. Now I can insert 3 million rows in 4 mins. I would like to move CSV into SQLite with parsing the column. If I did data type parsing in my code, its take long time to move data into SQLite (for 3 million rows and 40 columns it takes 25 minutes). Can I move 3 million records with data type parsing in less time?

Comment: One of the things I did was to use  CSVHelper to convert the csv contents using a configuration map

Comment: @Plutonix: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain me how to use CSVHelper?

Comment: If you go back to your old questions and mark any of those past answers which work as Accepted (click the checkmark), I'll undelete an answer posted.  Accepting answers and up voting (which you can do soon) helps other users find good answers.  its a way you can help others even if you are not inclined or not able to answer questions.  Your new question also makes it seem like you moved to SQL Server?

Comment: If I did data type parsing in my code, its take long time to move data into SQLite (for 3 million rows and 40 columns it takes 25 minutes). Is there any way to move 3 million records with data type parsing in less time?

Answer (score 0):

Doing one giant insert into resulting in a single ExecuteNonQuery() and a single transaction should increase performance. You could also try to import csv via processInfo.