# Binding Datatable to a datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a view model in my C# 4.0 app which has a `System.Data.DataTable` that's created in it using a service call. I want to bind this to a `datagrid` in my XAML file.

I tried following line DataGrid_Loaded event but its getting fired up before my datatable gets created inside the view model.

xaml:

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"/>
```

xaml.cs:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myViewModel.myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following suggestion: In your code behind you have to set grid's `DataContext` to your `DataTable`:

```
myDataGrid.DataContext = myViewModel.myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

In your XAML you need to indicate that the `ItemsSource` has to rely on binding:

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955956/3330348) for more details. Also, you can find a comprehensive example with explanations on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples).

EDIT:

Different approach would be to keep your table as a property. In your window to set the window's data context to the view model and then set the binding to the property in the view model:

The view model:

```
public DataTable myDataTable { get; set; }
```

In your window (the one that displays the data grid:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = myViewModel;
}
```

This way your binding in main window XAML will know where to search for the data - in `myViewModel`.

In your XAML you don't need a name for your grid using this approach. But the binding has to specify the name of the data source:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding myDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

Comment: Thanks PiotrWolkowski.I tried this, but I dont see any data on the UI screen although I see data in the datatable(while debugging).

Comment: @Mitu I added a different approach.

Comment: Thanks again.I tried your 2nd approach but no luck.

Comment: At this point it may be difficult to figure out what's your issue without more code. Can you show the `DataGrid` in xaml (together with parent container), your view model where you create a data table and the data table property, your view (what you've described as xaml.cs) where you set up a `DataContext`.