# DataGrid Cells Unselectable when setting DataContext from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

As the title says, cells unselectable when setting datacontext from code behind.

I am setting the `DataContext` as a `DataTable`.

Here's my `xaml`

```
<DataGrid Name="SQLResults" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

and here is my `c#`

```
SQLResults.DataContext = ReturnQueryAsDataTable(query);
```

Result is that no rows/cells/columns are selectable. I have tried all the variants of `ClipboardCopyMode`,`SelectionMode`,`SelectionUnit`

I want to be able to select values/data from my results. Anyone have any idea what I can do to resolve? Maybe I'm missing a setting.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `{Binding DefaultView}`?

see this post:
[How to bind DataTable to Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid)

Comment: I have no issues binding. The data shows up as intended. Just cannot select the cells. I would like to be able to copy/paste out of it.