# ASPX Gridview or formview

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a SQL table with 3 columns/ OrgID, SolutionName, ModelDescription

I want to create an aspx VB page that shows the data in the below format. The issue is it needs to auto create as the number of SolutionNames can vary by OrgID. and the number of ModelDescription can vary by SolutionName also.

View I am after is as below any help would be great.

```
OrgID   
SolutionName1    
ModelDescription1, Quantity    
ModelDescription2, Quantity    
ModelDescription3, Quantity    
SolutionName2    
ModelDescription1, Quantity    
ModelDescription2, Quantity    
SolutionName3    
ModelDescription1, Quantity
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering so quickly, can I ask a further question please? what sort of control do I need to add to the aspx page? gridview or list? and how do I populate the control from the datatable that the code created?

Answer (score 0):

See code below

```css
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim connStr As String = "Enter Your connection string here"
        'enter you SQL Here
        Dim SQL As String = "Select * from table1"

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(dt)

        'above code will create a data table that is the equivalent to the code below
        dt.Columns.Add("OrgID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("SolutionName", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ModelDescription", GetType(String))

        'you can then use groupby to group results
        Dim results = dt.AsEnumerable() _
                      .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("OrgID")).ToList()


    End Sub

End Module
​
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering so quickly, can I ask a further question please? what sort of control do I need to add to the aspx page? gridview or list? and how do I populate the control from the datatable that the code created?

Comment: See followqing webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid