# WPF Datagrid Binding Errors After Binding Is Set with MVVMLight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to bind a DataTable to a DataGrid using MVVMLight. I am able to get the data to show up however, when I try to scroll through the grid or edit cells, a number of binding errors appear. This seems to be causing performance issues, but I am also curious as to why they appear. In the code below, I just have one cell filled and the errors occur when I edit new cells. Other times I have tried this, I have created larger DataTables and the same errors occurred when I would scroll through the DataGrid. I have tried playing around with the properties of the DataGrid but nothing seems to get rid of the errors.

Edit: I have also tried using a DefaultView however that does not seem to fix the problem.

Here is my VM code:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace DatagridTest1.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    public DataTable Data2
        {
            get
            {
                return data2;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(() => Data2, ref data2, value);
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Data2 = new DataTable();

            DataColumn testCol = new DataColumn("Test1");
            Data2.Columns.Add(testCol);
            DataRow testRow = Data2.NewRow();
            testRow[0] = "0";
            Data2.Rows.Add(testRow);
            Data2.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DatagridTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatagridTest1"
        xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Focusable="False">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:Debug x:Key="Debugger"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data2, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource Debugger}}" DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here are the kind of errors I get:

```
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DatagridTest1\DatagridTest1\bin\Debug\DatagridTest1.vshost.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x18e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1e30 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DatagridTest1\DatagridTest1\bin\Debug\DatagridTest1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DatagridTest1\DatagridTest1\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DatagridTest1\DatagridTest1\bin\Debug\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ComponentModel.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DatagridTest1\DatagridTest1\bin\Debug\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ObjectModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Reflection\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Reflection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Globalization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Globalization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Linq.Expressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=64505930) for Binding (hash=49162568)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'Data2'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ItemsSource (hash=59593954)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=59593954) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Data2; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset; DataItem=null; target element is 'ColumnDefinition' (HashCode=15863087); target property is 'Width' (type 'GridLength')
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=59593954) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Activate with root item MainViewModel (hash=66305805)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930):   At level 0 - for MainViewModel.Data2 found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Data2)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): Replace item at level 0 with MainViewModel (hash=66305805), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Data2)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): GetValue at level 0 from MainViewModel (hash=66305805) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Data2): DataTable (hash=35951058)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): TransferValue - got raw value DataTable (hash=35951058)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 82 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): TransferValue - user's converter produced DataTable (hash=35951058)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): TransferValue - implicit converter produced DataView (hash=35751240 Count=1)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=64505930): TransferValue - using final value DataView (hash=35751240 Count=1)
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridDetailsPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation' (type 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Resources.ResourceManager\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=ValidationErrorTemplate; DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Template' (type 'ControlTemplate')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=NewItemMargin; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'Margin' (type 'Thickness')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridDetailsPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation' (type 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=ValidationErrorTemplate; DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Template' (type 'ControlTemplate')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
System.Windows.Data Information: 42 : BindingExpression path error: 'Test1' property not found for 'object' because data item is the NewItemPlaceholder. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='NamedObject' (HashCode=50804710); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='NamedObject' (HashCode=50804710); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='NamedObject' (HashCode=50804710); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='NamedObject' (HashCode=50804710); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CLIENTDIAGNOSTICS\XAMLDIAGNOSTICS\x86\WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'DatagridTest1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DatagridTest1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=NewItemMargin; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'Margin' (type 'Thickness')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridDetailsPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation' (type 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=ValidationErrorTemplate; DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Template' (type 'ControlTemplate')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=55668938); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'Test1' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=55668938); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=55668938); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'CellContent' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'Test1' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Test1; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=55668938); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use System.Data namespace classes in WPF. Create your own models with proper INotifyProperyChanged implementation and use ObservableCollection as your list.

However, if you still want to use DataTable, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid). (It looks like DataTable.DefaultView property is a key)

Comment: Thanks Matas. I forgot to mention I have already tried DataTable.DefaultView and it did not fix the problem. I will try using an ObservableCollection. The reason for using a DataTable was the ease in adding columns and rows. I'm trying to make an expandable spreadsheet.