# CSV data not rendering on WPF ui of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm new to C#,
CSV data not rendering on WPF ui of DataGrid, i'm getting data from csv but not able to display on ui , can any one help me out?

below is my XAML code-

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="825">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="217" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,33,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="707">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serials" Width="40" Binding="{Binding Serials}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Number}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="InstalledCode" Width="100" Binding="{Binding InstalledCode}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="InstalledTime" Width="100" Binding="{Binding InstalledTime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Location}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Site" Width="40" Binding="{Binding Site}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="UUID" Width="40" Binding="{Binding UUID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Uninstalled" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Uninstalled}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Notes}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>

</Window>
```

*Update1*:
below are the c# code:

```
private void LoadBound(string fName)
        {
            String textLine = string.Empty;
            String[] splitLine;
            var data = new DataTable();
            var sharath = new DataTable();
            data.Columns.AddRange(new[]
                                   {
                               new DataColumn ("Serials"),
                               new DataColumn ("Number"),
                               new DataColumn ("InstalledCode"),
                               new DataColumn ("InstalledTime"),
                               new DataColumn ("Location"),
                               new DataColumn ("Site"),
                               new DataColumn ("UUID"),
                               new DataColumn ("Uninstalled"),
                               new DataColumn ("Notes")

                            });
            data.Rows.Clear();

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fName))
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fName);

                var contents = objReader.ReadToEnd();

                var strReader = new System.IO.StringReader(contents);

                do
                {
                    textLine = strReader.ReadLine();
                    if (textLine != string.Empty)
                    {
                        splitLine = textLine.Split(',');
                        if (splitLine[0] != string.Empty || splitLine[1] != string.Empty)
                        {
                            data.Rows.Add(splitLine[0]);
                        }
                    }
                } while (strReader.Peek() != -1);

            }
            dataGrid1.DataContext = data;
        }
```

Update2:

My Csv file is

```
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Can anyone help me to populate data from csv to WPF Ui?

Comment: You're code is not actually trying to display CSV data, but a DataTable that you have created from the CSV file. That said, I think you need to set `dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;` rather than the DataContext - see this post for various ways to bind to a datatable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid

Answer (score 2):

you didn't set DataGrid.ItemsSource anythere.

if DataContext is set to DataTable, then ItemsSource can be set via binding in xaml :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultView}"
```

alternatively set ItemsSource from code:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;
```

Comment: only 1st row will get data and remaining rows are empty.@ASh

Comment: when i tried to  data.Rows.Add(splitLine[1]); and  data.Rows.Add(splitLine[2]); ....etc similarly but data appending in the same row(1st row). can you please tell me why?

Comment: @SharathkumarKG, I don't see any obvious problem with your code. I can recommend to inspect in debug how many lines you are getting from file, and which values they contains. Also [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines) is probably simpler method for the task

Comment: My csv file is added, splitLine[1] gets 10 and 1 from csv file similarly  splitLine[2] gets 20 and 2 from csv file