# How to add columns to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I'm basing myself on [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438) to show a DataGrid with some columns (no rows to be populated yet, just the columns):

I have following source code:

### cs file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DataTable dt_main;
    ...
}

private ...first_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    dt_main = new DataTable("dt_main"); // just a default name, no such table
    DataGrid1.DataContext = dt_main.DefaultView;
}

private ...second_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    dt_main.Columns.Clear();
    ...
    while (...)
      dt_main.Columns.Add(tmp_ColName);
}
```

### XAML file:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ... AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

I click on the `first_click` (this is for filling the list of tables) and then on `second_click` (this is for choosing the table), but although the DataTable's `Columns` attribute is filled in, I see nothing in my DataGrid, as you can see in following screenshot (the DataGrid is shown by the red arrow):

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Comment: What about DataGrid1.ItemsSource= dt_main.DefaultView;

Comment: @ziakhan: that would mean that both `DataGrid1.ItemsSource` and `DataGrid1.DataContext` need to equal `dt_main.DefaultView`? Looks weird. Nevertheless I tried it but it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are only auto-generated when the `ItemsSource` property is actually set.

Either set it explicitly after you have added the columns to the `DataTable` or also add the columns to the `DataGrid`:

```
private ...second_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    //add the columns to dt_main...

    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt_main.DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: You're a wizard! So, the `DataGrid` looses its connection to its `ItemsSource`, which MUST first be set to `null` and afterwards be set to the correct value in order to make this work. (I would never have thought about that)